# Check if APK has been built properly

Tags: android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, publishing, google-play

I recently had an issue with an Android application and I can't figure out what happened.
I was developing and testing my app via Eclipse and everything worked fine.
Then it was time to publish it on the PlayStyore (the version 1.0 was already published a few hours ago).
So I cleaned my workspace, and signed the APK via "Android Tools => Export signed application package" and uploaded the .apk on GooglePlay.
The uploading process completed without any issues.
When the app (1.0.1) got published on the PlayStore, I tried to download it and install it on my phone. It downloaded fine, but the app CRASHED after 1 second, not even the first screen appeared. (but it worked fine with my device connected to Eclipse, and I also sent the apk by email on my phone and installed it from there, no issue)

And everyone who installed the new version of my app couldn't launch it...

Here is the log I can see on GooglePlay

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   be.example.ex.Ex: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "be.example.ex.Ex" on path: /data/app/be.example.ex-2.apk at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4657)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "be.example.ex.Ex"
>   on path: /data/app/be.example.ex-2.apk at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
>   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504) ... 11
>   more

So I read a few posts on SO, I cleaned my project (again), unlinked the libraries of my project, then linked them back again.
I published the new APK, (1.0.2) and hopefully, everything worked fine, users could launch it after downloading it from PlayStore.

Now I have an other version to publish and I just can't get into the same issue. More people downloaded the app now and I can't afford the app to crash on every user's phone.

Is there a way to avoid the previous issue ? Maybe a tool to check if the apk has been built properly ?

Note this is the first time I get this error and I already published a few apps without any issue. I'm gonna freak out now every time I release a new version, so if someone could give me an advice to make sure this never happen again, this would be great :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: using Beta、Alpha stage on Google Play,https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but I got stuck with error 404 when trying to open the link they provide to send to testers.
They say it can take up to 24 hours so I'll wait a few hours.
This seemed the best approach to me.

Comment: @Seb83 did using Alpha/Beta stages on Google Play worked for you?

Comment: Yes it did. I finally got Alpha/Beta testing working and now I always publish the APK in BETA first. I can't afford to have the same issue as before anymore.

Answer (score 1):

May be the manifest is not correct
Please check with the intent filter

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the com.example.test.MainActivity should be declare correctly

Comment: Thanks but I already have the activities declared correctly in the manifest. That's what I don't understand. 
The error log read that my application class was not found...

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is check the apk made by eclipse. Sometimes, I have the same problem as a consequence before a new publish on google play store, I test my apk on my phone. Just with this following command line.

```
adb install pathToMyApk.apk
```

Comment: I'll give it a try with the previous .apk that was causing the issue, I will let you know

Comment: When you test your application in emulator, eclipse made a apk. When you export a apk, another apk is created but sometimes this apk is corrupted so if you test this apk on a phone and all is clean, you can publish it.

Comment: I had the same problem than OP and indeed, after installing the bad apk with adb, I could reproduce the problem.